# vec2 division acting weirdly (automatic aspect-ratio correction?)

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl

Running into some issues with vec2 divison with OpenGL ES with WebGL --- specifically that it seems to automatically deal with aspect ratios. My understanding is that:

```
someVec2 / anotherVec2 = vec2(
  someVec2.x / anotherVec2.x,
  someVec2.y / anotherVec2.y)
```

i.e., it is component-wise.

However, this code (where uResolution is an ivec2 passed from the code, of the current resolution):

```
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / float(uResolution);
gl_FragColor = vec4(uv.x, uv.y, 0.0, 1.0);
```

produces:

[image: broken example]

whereas

```
vec2 fragCoordUv = vec2(
  gl_FragCoord.x / float(uResolution.x),
  gl_FragCoord.y / float(uResolution.y)
);
gl_FragColor = vec4(uv.x, uv.y, 0.0, 1.0);
```

produces:

[image: correct example]

Specifically, the Y value doesn't seem to scale up all the way. The issue becomes more obvious if you use a texture. i.e. straight division:

[image: another broken example]

vs. manual component division:

[image: correct example]

It looks like it's automatically performing aspect ratio correction. Is this a feature? I can't seem to find any information on it anywhere. Everything states that normal binary operators (+, -, /, *, etc) just work component-based. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / vec2(uResolution);
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you. Do you know what's actually happening when you do `float(someiVec)`?

Comment: I suspect that float(uResolution) == float(uResolution.x)  and then when you divide a vec2 by a single float, each element is divided by that float independently.

Comment: `float` is a scalar type, so `float(someiVec)` first converts its argument to a scalar (by dropping all except the first component), and then converts that scalar to `float` type...